# Bootstrap and CSS - How to fix pill section?

Tags: html, tabs

I'm using getbootstrap tabs as part of an section with a total of 4 sections. I've tried multiple styles of tabs but once I duplicate the code to add another section it breaks and the tabs don't active the right pill section.  I wanted to be able to show the characters relationships in a more organized way.

[the format I'm trying to create with multiple pills][1]

````
<h3 style="margin-top:15px;color:#CBA135;"> Relationships</h3>
<div class="mb-2" style="height:2px;width:100%;background-color:#CBA135;"></div>
  <h3 style="margin-top:15px;color:#CBA135;">family</h3>
<div class="bd-example bd-example-tabs">
 <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
 <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
   <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
     <p>Consequat occaecat ullamco amet non eiusmod nostrud dolore irure incididunt est duis anim sunt officia. Fugiat velit proident aliquip nisi incididunt nostrud exercitation proident est nisi. Irure magna elit commodo anim ex veniam culpa eiusmod id nostrud sit cupidatat in veniam ad. Eiusmod consequat eu adipisicing minim anim aliquip cupidatat culpa excepteur quis. Occaecat sit eu exercitation irure Lorem incididunt nostrud.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">
     <p>Ad pariatur nostrud pariatur exercitation ipsum ipsum culpa mollit commodo mollit ex. Aute sunt incididunt amet commodo est sint nisi deserunt pariatur do. Aliquip ex eiusmod voluptate exercitation cillum id incididunt elit sunt. Qui minim sit magna Lorem id et dolore velit Lorem amet exercitation duis deserunt. Anim id labore elit adipisicing ut in id occaecat pariatur ut ullamco ea tempor duis.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">
     <p>Est quis nulla laborum officia ad nisi ex nostrud culpa Lorem excepteur aliquip dolor aliqua irure ex. Nulla ut duis ipsum nisi elit fugiat commodo sunt reprehenderit laborum veniam eu veniam. Eiusmod minim exercitation fugiat irure ex labore incididunt do fugiat commodo aliquip sit id deserunt reprehenderit aliquip nostrud. Amet ex cupidatat excepteur aute veniam incididunt mollit cupidatat esse irure officia elit do ipsum ullamco Lorem. Ullamco ut ad minim do mollit labore ipsum laboris ipsum commodo sunt tempor enim incididunt. Commodo quis sunt dolore aliquip aute tempor irure magna enim minim reprehenderit. Ullamco consectetur culpa veniam sint cillum aliqua incididunt velit ullamco sunt ullamco quis quis commodo voluptate. Mollit nulla nostrud adipisicing aliqua cupidatat aliqua pariatur mollit voluptate voluptate consequat non.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
 <h3 style="margin-top:15px;color:#CBA135;">family</h3>
<div class="bd-example bd-example-tabs">
 <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
 <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
   <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
     <p>Consequat occaecat ullamco amet non eiusmod nostrud dolore irure incididunt est duis anim sunt officia. Fugiat velit proident aliquip nisi incididunt nostrud exercitation proident est nisi. Irure magna elit commodo anim ex veniam culpa eiusmod id nostrud sit cupidatat in veniam ad. Eiusmod consequat eu adipisicing minim anim aliquip cupidatat culpa excepteur quis. Occaecat sit eu exercitation irure Lorem incididunt nostrud.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">
     <p>Ad pariatur nostrud pariatur exercitation ipsum ipsum culpa mollit commodo mollit ex. Aute sunt incididunt amet commodo est sint nisi deserunt pariatur do. Aliquip ex eiusmod voluptate exercitation cillum id incididunt elit sunt. Qui minim sit magna Lorem id et dolore velit Lorem amet exercitation duis deserunt. Anim id labore elit adipisicing ut in id occaecat pariatur ut ullamco ea tempor duis.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">
     <p>Est quis nulla laborum officia ad nisi ex nostrud culpa Lorem excepteur aliquip dolor aliqua irure ex. Nulla ut duis ipsum nisi elit fugiat commodo sunt reprehenderit laborum veniam eu veniam. Eiusmod minim exercitation fugiat irure ex labore incididunt do fugiat commodo aliquip sit id deserunt reprehenderit aliquip nostrud. Amet ex cupidatat excepteur aute veniam incididunt mollit cupidatat esse irure officia elit do ipsum ullamco Lorem. Ullamco ut ad minim do mollit labore ipsum laboris ipsum commodo sunt tempor enim incididunt. Commodo quis sunt dolore aliquip aute tempor irure magna enim minim reprehenderit. Ullamco consectetur culpa veniam sint cillum aliqua incididunt velit ullamco sunt ullamco quis quis commodo voluptate. Mollit nulla nostrud adipisicing aliqua cupidatat aliqua pariatur mollit voluptate voluptate consequat non.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>```


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0sgT.png
 [2]: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Id attribute of UL should be unique.

So, you should change the Id name of the ul tag after you duplicate nav-pill

```html
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">...</div>
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent2">...</div>
```

I hope this will be helpful to you.